# LeetCode - A solution passed on LeetCode submission, but returns null in IDE

Tags: java, linked-list, testcase

A link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/

This problem is about getting the intersection of two separate Linked Lists, and I have a solution which puts all the nodes in one Linked List into an ArrayList and just check whether the node in the other Linked List is contained in the ArrayList or not. The solution passes on LeetCode submission, but somehow just returns null in my IDE. I've tried variations of my test cases, but it all returns null. Here is the short solution to the problem and one of my test cases.

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x){
        this.val = x;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class Solution {
    public ListNode getIntersectionNodeUsingArrayList(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
        List<ListNode> list = new ArrayList<ListNode>();

        while(headA != null) {
            list.add(headA);
            headA = headA.next;
        }

        while(headB != null) {
            if(list.contains(headB)) {
                return headB;
            }

            headB = headB.next;
        }

        return null;
    }
public class TwoLL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        ListNode listA0 = new ListNode(4);
        listA0.next = new ListNode(1);
        listA0.next.next = new ListNode(8);
        listA0.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        listA0.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

        ListNode listB0 = new ListNode(5);
        listB0.next = new ListNode(0);
        listB0.next.next = new ListNode(1);
        listB0.next.next.next = new ListNode(8);
        listB0.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        listB0.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

        ListNode result = sol.getIntersectionNodeUsingArrayList(listA0, listB0);

        System.out.println(result.val); // should be 8 but it returns NPE since result is null.
        System.out.println(result); // returns null as well, instead of the memory address of the node
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn’t you be adding ListNode Val in the list? You are adding ListNode directly. It uses equals to compare the objects and it always returns false as default object compares address. That’s the problem.

Comment: There is no intersection in your test case because you are creating new nodes. The two lists are separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have built the list produces no intersection between them. The nodes belonging to the two lists are separate and there is no intersection.

```
listA0 4   ->  1  ->  8 -> 4 -> 5
listB0 5 -> 0 -> 1 -> 8 -> 4 -> 5
```

In the above, nodes 8, 4, 5 are *different* `ListNode` instances. Hence, they cannot be equal.

Try adding a common node to your list

```
ListNode common = new ListNode(10);
listA0.next.next.next.next.next = common;
listB0.next.next.next.next.next.next = common;
```

This prints result as `10`.

To simulate the case you've mentioned, the below should work

```
ListNode common  = new ListNode(8);
common.next = new ListNode(4);
common.next.next = new ListNode(5);

ListNode listA0 = new ListNode(4);
listA0.next = new ListNode(1);
listA0.next.next = common;


ListNode listB0 = new ListNode(5);
listB0.next = new ListNode(0);
listB0.next.next = new ListNode(1);
listB0.next.next.next = common;
```